# Update unresolvable problem

Tags: update-manager, held-packages

When I am try to update my system , I am getting the following error:

```
Could not initialise the package information    
An unresolvable problem occurred while initialising the package information.
Please report this bug for the 'update-manager' package and try to include the following error message:
'E:Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.'
```

How can I resolve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

open your terminal and do as

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get do-release-upgrade
```

[You might have to remove some repositories if they are failing](https://askubuntu.com/a/173209/5245)